# Resource recommendation for interpretation of quantum mechanics?

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse, decoherence

The jumping of the quantum state to one of the eigenstates of $Q$ is the process referred to as state-vector reduction or collapse of the wave function (where $Q$ is an observable).

I used to think that the above was a reasonable definition of collapse of the wave function and the interpretations were merely explaining why this was observed? However, it seems not to be the case. Where can I read more about:

- What exactly constitutes exactly of an "interpretation of quantum
  mechanics"
- The interpretations of quantum mechanics

Comment: "Foundations and Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics" by Gennaro Auletta  has good account of  interpretational issues.

Comment: Auletta later becomes more Everettian.

Comment: [More](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations+quantum-interpretations).

Comment: Wiki has a great list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics

Answer (score 2):

I have studied the informational interpretation and the Statistical Interpretation. Here is a list.

Informational Interpretation

1. QBism: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205039, https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantum-bayesian/, https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.5253
2. Relational quantum mechanics: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-relational/, https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9609002
3. Clifton, Bub, Halvorson: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0211089
4. R P Kostcki: https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.2423

Statistical Interpretation

1. L Ballentine: http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/3142, https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/RevModPhys.42.358

I am not a big fan of other interpretations so I don’t know proper references for them. An interpretation consists of explaining a theory using some other thing, most try to interpret using classical physics. Since information is a deep concept interpreting in terms of information is justified I feel.

Interpretation of quantum mechanics is a controversial subject. So proceed with caution. You should also look into those which get quantum mechanics from generalised probability theories for example Hardy, Mueller, Chiribella, Perinotti, etc.