# Books on the interpretations of Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, quantum-interpretations, foundations

I have a masters in theoretical physics, and throughout my studies I feel like the concept of 'interpretations of quantum mechanics' was never given any attention. All my quantum mechanics courses had the 'shut up and calculate' mentality. Although I think this is reasonable to some extend when learning the basics of quantum mechanics, I currently feel like it is something that is missing. It is an interesting subject that I feel like I should have at least a basic understanding of.

What book/resource would you recommend to study up on the wealth of interpretations that are out there? I would like something that explains the different interpretations, their motivations, and their downsides. Preferably something that is somewhat up to date.

I am not afraid of mathematics and technical details (in fact, I prefer a book that doesn't dumb things down, at the very least I am *not* looking for a pop. sci. book). I know that similar questions have been asked before, but I haven't found a satisfactory answer.

Some books that I am considering buying:

- *Foundations And Interpretation Of Quantum Mechanics: In The Light Of A Critical-historical Analysis Of The Problems And Of A Synthesis Of The Results*, by Gennaro Auletta. A 1000 page tomb might be a bit long for my purpose (although I don't discount it straight away). I find it difficult to gauge what the target audience is; is it so long because it spends a lot of time on the basics of QM? I also couldn't find a table of contents for this book, so I am really not sure what to expect.
- *The Philosophy of Quantum Physics*, by Corb Friede et al. This books seems like it touches most things that I want, however it is *"aimed at philosophers with an interest in physics"*, while I am more looking for something aimed at physicists with an interest in philosophy.
- *The Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics*, by Roland Omnes. Aimed at undergraduate physics students means that it probably has a decent level of detail (although I would prefer a book aimed at graduate students). The main thing I am afraid of is that it is missing out on some important results and new ideas from the past 30 years.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112968/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/368519/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/386126/2451 and links therein.